# How to read out to text file

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I need to output to a txt file.. I am able to output my words but not my BST.I'm trying to get my binary tree in inorder, preorder and postorder to output in my txt file. How do I do this?? My code is below:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Project3 {
    public Node root;

    public Project3 insert(int number) {
        Node node = new Node(number);

        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return this;
        }

        insertValue(root, node);
        return this;

    }

    public class Node {

        public int number;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        public Node(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
    }

    private void insertValue(Node newRoot, Node node) {
        if (newRoot.number > node.number) {
            if (newRoot.left == null) {
                newRoot.left = node;
                return;
            } else {
                insertValue(newRoot.left, node);
            }
        } else {
            if (newRoot.right == null) {
                newRoot.right = node;
                return;
            } else {
                insertValue(newRoot.right, node);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printInorder() {
        printInOrderImplem(root);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void printPreorder() {
        PreOrderImplem(root);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void printPostorder() {
        printPostOrderImplem(root);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private void printInOrderImplem(Node currRoot) {
        if (currRoot == null) {
            return;
        }
        printInOrderImplem(currRoot.left);
        System.out.print(currRoot.number + ", ");
        printInOrderImplem(currRoot.right);
    }

    private void PreOrderImplem(Node currRoot) {
        if (currRoot == null) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.print(currRoot.number + ", ");
        PreOrderImplem(currRoot.left);
        PreOrderImplem(currRoot.right);
    }

    private void printPostOrderImplem(Node currRoot) {
        if (currRoot == null) {
            return;
        }
        printPostOrderImplem(currRoot.left);
        printPostOrderImplem(currRoot.right);
        System.out.print(currRoot.number + ", ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/Desktop/output.txt"));
        Project3 BST = new Project3();

        // numbers to insert 14, 15, 4, 9, 7, 18, 3, 5, 16, 4, 20, 17, 9, 14, 5
        BST.insert(14);
        BST.insert(15);
        BST.insert(4);
        BST.insert(9);
        BST.insert(7);
        BST.insert(18);
        BST.insert(3);
        BST.insert(5);
        BST.insert(16);
        BST.insert(4);
        BST.insert(20);
        BST.insert(17);
        BST.insert(9);
        BST.insert(14);
        BST.insert(5);

        System.out.println("Inorder traversal is- ");
        out.println("Inorder traversal is- ");
        BST.printInorder();

        System.out.println("Preorder traversal is- ");
        out.println("Preorder Traversal is- ");
        BST.printPreorder();

        System.out.println("Postorder traversal is- ");
        out.println("Postorder Traversal is- ");
        BST.printPostorder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to write to a txt file

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
try { 
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("example.txt");
    writer.print("stuff in my .txt");
    writer.println();
    writer.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
}
```

Note that the .txt (or any file you write, for that matter) will be in the same directory as your .java. If you want it to be in a different directory, you must input the directory before the name of the file. (ie. "filename/example.txt")

Answer (score 0):

Your `printXorder()` methods always print to `System.out`, so you'll never see that in the file on disk. You have several options, I'll explain the main two:

- instead of implementing `printXorder()` methods, use `toStringXorder()`, which return a `String` which you can then print to whatever stream you like. If you do this, you should use a `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer` if your code is reentrant) during the `String` construction phase, and convert it to `String` only as the very last step. Also, the `StringBuilder` allows you to easily remove that nasty last comma you get with your implementation (if you choose to remove the comma, be careful about `toString`ing an empty tree).
- Let your `printXorder()` methods take a `PrintStream` parameter and make them print to that `PrintStream`.

The first solution is OK (and generally more flexible) if your tree is not going to grow too much. If the tree can get very large (so that the resulting `String` will cause trouble to fit in memory), you'll need the second one.